# Central Limit Theorem- Lapunow, Linderberg

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems

I have a task: $(X_n)_{n>=1}$ are independent. $P(X_n=0)=1/n$ and $P(X_n=2n)=1-1/n$.
Check the weak convergence
$\frac{X_1+X_2+X_3+....+X_n}{n}-n$. 
I tried use the Lapunow theorem or Linderberg theorem to $X_{n,k}=\frac{X_k}{n}-1$. But the variance converges to infinity.

Thanks in advance.